# Trying to do a Merge. What is the best way to handle headers, which consist of incrementing numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, header

I did a transpose of my dataframe and now I have headers that consist of numbers from 1 - 21384.

```
df_final.columns.values
Out[39]: array([    0,     1,     2, ..., 21382, 21383, 21384], dtype=int64)

                       0       1       2       3      ...   21381   21382  \
qyear                 2011Q1  2012Q1  2013Q1  2011Q1  ...  2013Q1  2011Q1   
RCFD3531                   0       0       0       0  ...       0       0   
RCFD3532                   0       0       0       0  ...       0       0   
RCFD3533                   0       0       0       0  ...       0       0   
RCFD3541                   0       0       0       0  ...       0       0
```

Is there a way to eliminate these headers and replace them with row #1?  Or, perhaps ignore them?  Or maybe update them based on row #1?  The actual headers that I want to use are in the row named 'qyear':

```
qyear                 2011Q1  2012Q1  2013Q1  2011Q1  ...  2013Q1  2011Q1
```

Basically, I want to do a merge, and it's not working.

```
df_final = pd.merge(df_final, df_list, left_on='qyear', right_on='IDRSSD_ID', how='inner')

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-42-324d32761a8c>", line 1, in <module>
    df_final = pd.merge(df_final, df_list, left_on='qyear', right_on='IDRSSD_ID', how='inner')

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 87, in merge
    validate=validate,

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 652, in __init__
    ) = self._get_merge_keys()

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 1018, in _get_merge_keys
    left_keys.append(left._get_label_or_level_values(lk))

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1563, in _get_label_or_level_values
    raise KeyError(key)

KeyError: 'qyear'
```

Comment: That does fix the header problem!!  Sweet!!  However, I still can't do the merge.  I'm getting the same error as before: KeyError: 'qyear'

Comment: Yeah `qyear` is your index - it's not a column.  You can either use `reset_index` or you can look at merging on index, there are examples of how to do that in the documentation.

Comment: Got everything working now!  Thanks for the point in the right direction here!  Really appreciate it!!